# Laravel - print_r in twig view

Tags: php, laravel, twig

I have a "simple" question I would hope, and that is how can I print_r or at least see the contents of all defined variables in a twig file.

I have tried: `{{ variable }}` (where variable is an array set for the view

```
$viewData['variable'] = array('1','2','3');
```

in the controller.

I have also tried: `{{ $variable }}`  That gives an error.

I would just want to know what is available from my array in the twig file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the built in `{{ dump() }}` function. See the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/dump.html).

If you use it without any value in the brackets it will dump all variables available.
For dumping only your array you would do it like this:

`{{ dump(viewData) }}`

With something like xdebug the output looks quite nice and is readable.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Although the documentation says it's not available by default it was added in twig 1.5 and should be ready to use by default.

Of course not the same as `print_r` but with xdebug enabled it outputs nice and readable `var_dump` information.

Comment: As of Twig 1.5, the Debug extension has been deprecated, so dump() should be availabe by default:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Comment: In Laravel 5.4 in config-> twigbridge.php set environment to 'debug' => config('app.debug', true) Now twigbridge debug is enabled on Laravel env

Answer (score 8):

The dump function works but requires the [debug option enabled](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) in the environment. If you don't have the ability to set this you can also just loop through the array:

```
<pre>
{% for key, item in variable %}
    * {{ key }} - {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about doing it in Twig but you can use Laravel's `dd` helper to dump and die from within the controller.

```php
dd($viewData['variable']);
```

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with Twig

Comment: The question is tagged `laravel` and I was the one who re-tagged it as `twig`. Cheers @Webberig.

Comment: My mistake, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.4 in `config`-> `twigbridge.php` set `environment` to `'debug' => config('app.debug', true)`
Now twigbridge debug is enabled on Laravel env